# How can I create one linux shell command out of two commands that behaves like standard piping?

Tags: python, bash, hadoop, gzip, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to use Hadoop Streaming to run two commands such as `gunzip | map_to_old_format.py`, but it errors with gzip saying "|.gz not found" or something along those lines (only when run through Hadoop.. if I run on command line, it works fine).

Since I can't figure out how to gunzip in Python on the fly, I would like to create one shell script that does this command combining for me (e.g. `gunzip_and_map_to_old.sh`).  I tried this with the following, but gzip didn't like (gzip complains "gzip: stdin: not in gzip format"):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read data; do
    echo $data | gunzip | map_to_old_format.py $2
done
```

Regarding python gunzip, I tried `f = gzip.GzipFile("", "rb", fileobj=sys.stdin)` as well as a Wrapper method described [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-January/063986.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about Hadoop, but I'm going to guess that `echo $data | gunzip` doesn't work because `$data` is a line of `data`, and `$data` by itself is probably not in the gzip format. Instead of passing it the data line by line, can't you just do this in the bash script file?

```
#!/bin/bash
gunzip | map_to_old_format.py
```

You can then call it by passing in the gzip file like this:

```
cat data.gz | gunzip_and_map_to_old.sh
```

Comment: Well, that was more simple that I figured it would be! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer my exact question, but I was able to bypass it by adding `-jobconf
stream.recordreader.compression=gzip` to my Hadoop command ([source where I learned this](http://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg00422.html)):

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar \
    -jobconf stream.recordreader.compression=gzip \
    -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
    -file map_to_old_format.py \
    -mapper map_to_old_format.py \
    -input /mydata/* -output output/newdata
```

**Note:** I am stil curious how to accomplish the above via shell-scripting, so if it is possible, please let me know.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it that way? I think you could also use -D mapred.input.compression.codec='org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec'

Comment: Nothing wrong with this way, nor your way. I just discovered it after I posted my question, but was curious as to how the shell-scripting method could be used hypothetically (which redcurry nailed w/ his answer). Thanks for this alternative setting :)

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop streaming usually reads the input files using TextInputFormat, and passes it line by line to your python mapper via std in (with the tab character separating the Key and Value (in most cases a line number and the line text).

If the file extension of the input file doesn't end in .gz, then hadoops TextInputFormat will not know the gunzip the file contents before passing you the lines one at a time. You can, as suggested in other answers, configure properties to force hadoop to gunzip the file.